# Node js vs Django vs Flask for multiple videos streaming from python

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I got 6 real-time videos which are inference output from heavy deep learning calculation from python, and I've tried to display them to PyQt that lots of threading issues with ugly GUI!!. So, I want to use a framework only to display well and fancy GUI! There seem lots of frameworks based on my google search, and I have no idea

which one is the best for my current project among Node js, Django, and Flask!

1. I need to display 6 real-time videos with 10~15 FPS.
2. Communicating well with python.
3. Easy to build GUI, I have some features like logging, displaying real-time graph(optional)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For video streaming, you will require to setup a **socket URL** for listening to incoming packet. Definitely, you can dedicate a server just for this to handle high amount of traffic.

Now, as such it dependents on your application, if you are just going to use it for streaming then Flask will do, it is lightweight. On the other hand, Django and NodeJS provides ready made function for socket programming and they are very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it doesn't really matter much as Django would be good because of its  pre built features... Plus data transfer is very reliable in django along with your expertise in python, django is preferred. NodeJs would be easier to implement tho. Really prefers upon you, but both django and nodeJs works pretty well.

Sorry, no idea on flask